# How to auto maximize window screen when link is opened?

Tags: html, jsp

I am wondering how to set the browser to auto maximize the window screen when a link is opened?

Below the sample codes:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com"  target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

The things is it is always opening as a small screen. What I want is a full windows screen at all times. I am using a JSP Page as a front end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fullScreen(theURL) {
window.open(theURL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fullScreen('http://www.w3schools.com');">Visit W3Schools</a>
</body>
</html>
```