# How to auto maximize a chrome window using html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to automatically maximize the active browser window.

This example is working well with MS explorer:

[How to auto maximize window screen when link is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121203/how-to-auto-maximize-window-screen-when-it-is-opened)

But it is not working with Chrome. How to do it compliant for Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this piece of code from [super user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen) which uses the Chrome Fullscreen API

```
var el = document.documentElement
    , rfs = // for newer Webkit and Firefox
           el.requestFullScreen
        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
        || el.mozRequestFullScreen
        || el.msRequestFullScreen
;
if(typeof rfs!="undefined" && rfs){
  rfs.call(el);
} else if(typeof window.ActiveXObject!="undefined"){
  // for Internet Explorer
  var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  if (wscript!=null) {
     wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
  }
}
```